# Create a column with a random number for each exact match of two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a `NEW_ID` column with a unique value for each exact match of `FIRST_NM`, `LAST_NM`.

```
data = np.array([['John', 'Smith', 1], ['John', 'West', 7], ['Eric', 'Adams', 9], 
                 ['Jane', 'Doe', 14], ['Jane', 'Doe', 16], ['John', 'Smith', 19]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM', 'PAGE_NUM'])

  FIRST_NM LAST_NM PAGE_NUM
0     John   Smith        1
1     John    West        7
2     Eric   Adams        9
3     Jane     Doe       14
4     Jane     Doe       16
5     John   Smith       19
```

The desired dataframe:

```
  FIRST_NM LAST_NM PAGE_NUM  NEW_ID
0     John   Smith        1     654
1     John    West        7     123
2     Eric   Adams        9      78
3     Jane     Doe       14       3
4     Jane     Doe       16       3
5     John   Smith       19     654
```

I figured I should do something like the code below but I know it's not right ...

```
import random
df.groupby(['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM']).apply(lambda group: random.getrandbits(16))
```

Comment: Did you consider using some good hash function?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux That sound like it could be a good idea. Can you suggest an example?

Comment: Sure, see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original version would work if you used `transform`, which broadcasts the result back up to the original indices:

```
>>> df["NEW_ID"] = df.groupby(['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM']).transform(lambda group: 
    random.getrandbits(16))
>>> df
  FIRST_NM LAST_NM PAGE_NUM NEW_ID
0     John   Smith        1  57757
1     John   Smith        7  57757
2     Eric   Adams        9  46139
3     Jane     Doe       14  55091
4     Jane     Doe       16  55091
5     John   Smith       19  57757
```

But I'm not a big fan of just taking random numbers and hoping for the best (i.e. no collisions.) If you have a range-like index like your example has, you can use that instead:

```
>>> df.groupby(['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM'])["PAGE_NUM"].transform("idxmin")
0    0
1    0
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Or the ranked version:

```
>>> df.groupby(['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM'])["PAGE_NUM"].transform("idxmin").rank("dense")
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    1
dtype: float64
```

Once you have those you can map them into unique random numbers safely however you like.

---

Unfortunately I don't think the only place the group assignments are located is guaranteed, namely

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(["FIRST_NM", "LAST_NM"])
>>> grouped.grouper.group_info[0]
array([2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

I wouldn't mind a `groupcount()` method which returned either this or the "rank in order of first occurrence" version.

Answer (score 1):

You could add column with some good hash function, either faster but less secure (like cityhash in example below), or go with crypto-secure hash, or even some AES based transformation. Obviously, if name is the same, ID will be the same. Last name and first name joined by `_`, you could use any symbol you want

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyhash

data = np.array([['John', 'Smith', 1], ['John', 'Smith', 7], ['Eric', 'Adams', 9],
             ['Jane', 'Doe', 14], ['Jane', 'Doe', 16], ['John', 'Smith', 19]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM', 'PAGE_NUM'])
print(df)

hasher = pyhash.city_64()

df['FULL_ID'] = df[['FIRST_NM', 'LAST_NM']].apply(lambda x: hasher('_'.join(x)), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use groupby.  You're probably better off making a dict with the mapping and then just using `map` to assign it:

```
nameIDs = {name: ix for name, ix in zip(df.FIRST_NM.unique(), range(df.FIRST_NM.nunique()))}
df['NEWID'] = df.FIRST_NM.map(nameIDs)
```

Then:

```
>>> df
  FIRST_NM LAST_NM PAGE_NUM  NEWID
0     John   Smith        1      0
1     John   Smith        7      0
2     Eric   Adams        9      1
3     Jane     Doe       14      2
4     Jane     Doe       16      2
5     John   Smith       19      0
```

Here I just generated the IDs as sequential integers.  You can certainly adapt this to use random numbers if you want, although I don't really see why you would want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I probably didn't supply enough information about the data. Not all the first names of "John" have "Smith" as the last name. So I need to consider the first and last names together, not just unique first names. I will edit the data in the question to better reflect my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've found an answer by now in the past 5 years, but just create a key column and then run the above code based off that key (the combination of first and last names)

Comment: You can make your answer more informative by providing a single line of code.